# How center a "picture link" in the header

Tags: design, header

I am in charge of a Magento website created by a former guy and I followed this tutorial to add a new Picture Link in my header :

https://kamaradski.com/831/how-to-add-a-picture-link-in-magento-header

This worked but despite the "align = center " the "picture link" stay next to the logo of the company. You can see that on the photo below, the red part is the "picture link" the black next to the red one is the company logo.

[image: MagentoWebsite]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to this file

```
app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

add code after this

```
<a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="large" />
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrcSmall() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="small" />
    </a>
```

Comment: That's what I did and the picture link is still not centered, still next to the magento logo

Comment: Add style="margin-left:200px" inside  your img tag